# Oracle SQL | Merge-Select-Update Clause | Subset of Target Table

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

***What I intend to do?***
To update a few target table fields for sub-set of matched target records, getting matched between source and target, provided they both being the same table.

***Where I need help?***
`Merge-into-`*target*`-using-select-`*source*`-on-` clause seems to have control only for two categories-

- When Source and Target records match, update **all** matching target records
- When Source and Target records does not match, **insert** or perform other control operations.

In my case, When Source and Target records match, I'd like to perform update on **Not all** records of target but on a **sub-set of target records**.

Requesting help to guide on this.

For reference here's the code(target filter qualifier commented, as it won't work for sure):

```
MERGE INTO TGT
USING (
SELECT id, account_number, part_role, inc_val, pay_frequency, 
period, pay_option, inclusion_value 
FROM Table_1
WHERE id = var1
AND account_number = var2
AND part_role in ('YY','XX')
) SRC
ON (
SRC.id = TGT.id
AND SRC.account_number = TGT.account_number
--TGT.part_role in ('AA','BB','CC','DD','EE') --This must be a wrong place for this qualifier, please help on where to include this qualifier for filtering out target records for update purpose
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
TGT.inc_val = SRC.inc_val 
,TGT.pay_frequency = SRC.pay_frequency 
,TGT.period = SRC.period 
,TGT.pay_option = SRC.pay_option 
,TGT.inclusion_value = SRC.inclusion_value;
```

**Other Associated Details**
Database: Oracle
Version: 11gR2
Environment: Unix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `where` clause after `SET` statements.

```
MERGE INTO TGT
USING (SELECT
  id,
  account_number,
  part_role,
  inc_val,
  pay_frequency,
  period,
  pay_option,
  inclusion_value
FROM Table_1
WHERE id = var1
AND account_number = var2
AND part_role IN ('YY', 'XX')) SRC
ON (
SRC.id = TGT.id
AND SRC.account_number = TGT.account_number
--TGT.part_role in ('AA','BB','CC','DD','EE') --This must be a wrong place for this qualifier, please help on where to include this qualifier for filtering out target records for update purpose
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
TGT.inc_val = SRC.inc_val
, TGT.pay_frequency = SRC.pay_frequency
, TGT.period = SRC.period
, TGT.pay_option = SRC.pay_option
, TGT.inclusion_value = SRC.inclusion_value
WHERE TGT.part_role in ('AA','BB','CC','DD','EE');
```

Comment: Thanks Kaushik! My bad, I couldn't think through this fix :)